# How can I get the records (of a specific model) of both request.user and a specific user?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am not very professional in django rest...

I wrote a blog with django rest framework and There is no problem when I want to get all the records related to the Article model or get a specific article, for example

But what I want to do is to send an user id(or an user name) to the view when I click on the user's name.

and as a result display all the records of the Article model related to the request.user and all the records of the Article model related to the user whose name was clicked.

In fact, I want to click on the name of each user, in addition to getting the Articles of that user, the Articles related to the request.user will also be taken

This is what I have done so far...

```
#models.py

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField
    author = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(null = True)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="img", blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username






#views.py

class ArticleCreate(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

class ArticleList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

class ArticleDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

class UserDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserProfile(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer






#serializers.py

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = "__all__"
              
        
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = "__all__"


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ['updated' , 'created']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should directly make several modifications in `get_queryset()` method by using [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) objects so:

```py
class ArticleList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.kwargs.get('user_id')
        if user_id:
            articles = Article.objects.filter(Q(author_id=user_id) | Q(author=self.request.user))
            return articles
        return self.queryset
```

You'll also need to modify your urls.py file to include the `user_id` parameter in the URL so:

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import ArticleList

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/<int:user_id>/', ArticleList.as_view(), name='article_list'),
    # ... Other routes.
]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works correctly, but what should I do if I want the articles of the request.user and the clicked user to be returned in order and based on the creation date?

Comment: @mehdi you can just do `.order_by("created")`.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything is working properly

Answer (score 1):

example URL: http://example.com/api/purchases?username=denvercoder9

```
class ArticleList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username')
        if username:
           return User.objects.filter(username=username).article_set.all()
        user = self.request.user
        return Article.objects.filter(author=user)
```